# Rdlc Showing information in square blocks like form

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2

Actually I have to create a report in rdlc report viewer. In that I want to show information in blocks form like each block will contain 1 character. for ex. I have a string "Test", i want to show like 'T' in one box, 'e' in another and so on...

[image]

I have one logic to create those squares that I can create tables with small columns. But the problem is how to fill data (each character) from string what I will pass in dataset. Is there any other solution which can I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mid` function for every `TextBox` in your `Table`.

For example, `Channel` field has a maximum of 10 characters so you can use this set of expressions, one in each box:

```
=Mid(Fields!Channel.Value, 1, 1)
=Mid(Fields!Channel.Value, 2, 1)
=Mid(Fields!Channel.Value, 3, 1)
=Mid(Fields!Channel.Value, 4, 1)
...
=Mid(Fields!Channel.Value, 10, 1)
```